# Multi line comment in ZipArchive

Tags: php, zip, php-7, php-ziparchive, winrar

I am trying to set a multi-line comment with ZipArchive.Below is a simplified demo.

```
<?php
$comment = "File \t Stats\r\n";
$comment .= "Second line ...some another text \r\n";
$zip->setArchiveComment($comment);
```

I then open the zip file with Winrar on my windows machine and in the comment you can see `\r\n` , `\t` appearing as is ... indicating that either winrar don't allow this or i wrong set the zipArchive comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem based on your simplified demo. WinRAR displays it as expected. But I can mimic the result you get by using [single quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) for the comment string.

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('test.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
if ($res === TRUE) {
    $zip->addFromString('test.txt', 'file content goes here');

    $zip->setArchiveComment("File \t Stats\r\nSecond line ... some other text \r\n"); // OK
    $comment = "File \t Stats\r\n";
    $comment .= 'Second line ... some other text \r\n';
    $zip->setArchiveComment($comment); // NOT OK for the second line

    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

Comment: @Gfy....Thanks for your answer...it turn out i was using single quotes by mistake in another method